# Firebase JavaScript Child Comparison

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I need to compare some values in my Firebase Database using JavaScript, but I'm having a hard time doing that. See image above.

The way that is suppose to work is I need to check if the user likes the same id as the other user. So for example:

User `XbsX0IskrHVcaEmEBgyeok9isiM2` liked 4 items with unique ID's. Now I need to check if user `jBc2Ls32DgMUSgzKUkVSw38UjQD2` liked the same thing to see if it's a match.

I have this code:

```
var check = ref.child('likes').child(uid2).child(uid2);
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the likes of the first user and make sure that everyone exists on the list of likes of the second user:

```
// Gets the list of likes from both users
var likes_user_1 = ref.child('likes').child(uid1);
var likes_user_2 = ref.child('likes').child(uid2);

// Iterates over the list of likes of the first user
var isAMatch = Object.keys(likes_user_1).every(function(like) {
  // Returns true if user_2 has this like
  return likes_user_2[like];
});
```